# How does the middlewares work in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

when ever the request is made from client to server, The app.use() middleware methods will be executed first (Please correct me if I am wrong) .
when we are requesting the server for the first time, we will get the object of the request through middleware bodyparser , After exectution of bodyparser middleware , it retrieves the password from `request.body["password"]` in the next middleware function. Does the value of `req.body["password"]
will be undefined initially or it skips the 2nd middle ware. We are getting the value after entering something and clicking submit button  on client side. Explain if one knows about this.

```
// index.js

import express from "express"
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath((import.meta.url)))

const app = express()
const port = 3000
let userPassword = "";
// 1st middle ware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// 2nd middle ware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    userPassword = req.body['password']
    next()
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")
    //index.html has an input and a button.
})

app.post("/check", (req, res) => {
    if (userPassword == "ILoveProgramming") {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/secret.html")
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")
    }
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`)
})
```

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Secrets</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Secrets</h1>
  <form action="/check" method="POST">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<!-- secret.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Secrets</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Secrets</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>When making chocolate desserts, always add a little salt. It makes the chocolate flavour more intense.</li>
    <li>Whenever you travel abroad bring a new soundtrack for each place you visit, preferably one you have never heard
      before.
      In the future, every time you listen to each soundtrack again they will bring you vivid memories of the places you
      have
      visited.</li>
    <li>Do not try to be the person your parents would want you to be. Be the person you would like your child to be be.
      It more
      clearly
      defines your own convictions, desires, goals, and motivates you to be your best.</li>
    <li>If a friend or a family member gets diagnosed with dementia or alzheimer, in the early stages try to find out
      what their
      favorite songs of all time are. In this way you would be able to create a playlist for them that could be of great
      benefit in the later stages of the disease.</li>
    <li>When a friend is upset, ask them one simple question before saying anything else: 'Do you want to talk about it
      or do
      you want to be distracted from it?'</li>
    <li>If you ever forget your WiFi password or you want to get your school WiFi password etc. Just type this command
      into the
      command line of a computer already connected to that WiFi: netsh wlan show profile WiFi-name key=clear</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Explain briefly about the flow of the code on server side.

Comment: Each of the middlewares looks at the incoming data. If it matches the type of data it's designed to process, it updates `req` to contains its results.

Comment: You absolutely must not structure your code this way, because if you have multiple users accessing your service everyone shares the same `userPassword`. Once `userPassword` is set, it's set for everyone.